# Can we save java file without .java extension?

Tags: java

If we have file sample, instead of saving sample.  Java if we save it as

- sample.j or
- sample.ja or
- sample.jav

Will the program work or not?

Comment: You have to be WAY more specific. For example, what program are you talking about?

Comment: If you're talking about the Java compiler, you could have just tried it...

Comment: You can save it by any name but compiler will not compile if extension is not .java, hence .class file will not be created.

Comment: Like `.htm` and `.html`.Answer:`NO`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

No, the java-compiler only works with `.java` extensions.
why would you want to do that anyways?

Comment: It's designed to work with `*.java` files but if you specify a file name, it can be anything.  It looks for other classes to compile by name and it assumes they are `*.java`